# Vuex access data property

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using [vue-offline](https://github.com/filrak/vue-offline) but I can't use it in store to check online status.

In components I can access as:

```
if (this.isOnline)
```

or in template with

```
v-if="isOnline"
```

In store (module) I tried:

```
if (this._vm.$isOnline)
```

but it returns always false.

How do I access it in vuex?

Comment: Why can't you just pass it as an argument to action/mutation? Otherwise you might face circular dependency issues.

Comment: Feels like an XY issue: the VueX store should not be able to access a Vue components data: instead, whatever data that is in the store should be received in the form of actions/mutations sent from the Vue components. For a component that uses the VueOffline mixin, listen to the `online`/`offline` event that triggers a mutation in the store that updates the store's own `isOnline` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the online status as an argument from your component...

or you can easily check the online status using navigator.onLine (used by vue-offline, [see the file](https://github.com/filrak/vue-offline/blob/master/src/index.js)).

So it will be in your store:

```
if (navigator.onLine)
```

Here is an example showing the online status in the console using both methods:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-9zhy3